# how to set up p4 view to avoid file(s) not on client issue

Tags: windows, perforce

I try to run p4 on windows' powershell, and here is my problem.

> p4 client

```
...
Host: my_machine
Root: C:\mywork\
...
View: //gmag/a/b/c/... //my_machine/gmag/a/b/c/...
...
```

Now I want to edit a file at:
C:\mywork\gmag\a\b\c\d\e\this_file
so I am running:

> cd C:\mywork\gmag\a\b\c\d\e
> p4 edit this_file

my_file - file(s) not on client

I also tried:

> cd C:\mywork\gmag\a\b\c
> p4 edit this_file

my_file - file(s) not on client

> cd C:\mywork\gmag\a\b\c
> p4 edit .\d\e\this_file

my_file - file(s) not on client

Does anyone know what is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, the thing that's missing is the client file.  Do:

```
p4 sync this_file
```

That will sync the file from the depot to your client, and then you can `edit` it.  To save time when you need to edit another file, you might want to just sync your entire workspace:

```
p4 sync
```

If syncing doesn't work, try `p4 files this_file` to see if it even exists in the depot.  If it doesn't exist in the depot but it *does* exist on your client, you need to `add` it, not `edit` it.

Comment: Note that if the file exists both in the depot and in your workspace, but was not synced, you're probably doing something weird that is making your life more difficult than it should be, like downloading the files and putting them in your workspace manually instead of just letting `p4 sync` do all the work for you. :)